# how do I stop looping in php and wait for user input to continue the loop?

Tags: php, forms, loops, submit

Is it possible to stop php loop in while or for and wait for user input to continue the loop?

For example, I loop a single form for 5 times.
I want each form to appear one by one after I submit the form instead of all 5 forms appear together

all suggestion is highly appreciated..:)

Comment: You can use isset to check if the previous form was submitted

Comment: Agree with @Rizier123 . You can check if the previous form was submitted. You can use javaScript to check it.

Answer (score 0):

This could look something like this:

(Here i'm using session so i can display every form every time if they was submitted once)

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['submit1']) && !empty($_POST['test1']))
        $_SESSION['form2'] = TRUE;

    if(isset($_POST['submit2']) && !empty($_POST['test2']))
        $_SESSION['form3'] = TRUE;

    echo '
        form1:
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="test1">
            <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="submit">
        </form>
    ';

    if(isset($_SESSION['form2']) && $_SESSION['form2']) {

        echo '
            form2:
            <form action="" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="test2">
                <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="submit">
            </form>
        ';
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['form3']) && $_SESSION['form3']) {

        echo '
            form3:
            <form action="" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="test3">
                <input type="submit" name="submit3" value="submit">
            </form>
        ';
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is executed on server, so what you see in your browser viewport is the output of the script, which was done executing a long time ago. That means no interfering with the `while` loop

However, there is a solution for your problem.
First is output based on `if-statements` and sessions

```
<?php

session_start();

// determine which form to display
if ($_REQUEST["form1"]) {
    $_SESSION["form"] = 1;
}
elseif($_REQUEST["form2"]) {
    $_SESSION["form"] = 2;
}
elseif($_REQUEST["form3"]) {
    $_SESSION["form"] = 3;
}

if($_SESSION["form"] >= 1) {
    echo ' Form 1 output ';
}
if($_SESSION["form"] >= 2) {
    echo ' Form 2 output ';
}
if($_SESSION["form"] >= 3) {
    echo ' Form 3 output ';
}

?>
```

Second might be jquery utilizing form id's

```
<head>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form1").submit(function(event) {
            // prevent default submitting and display the next form
        });
        $("#form2").submit(function(event) {
            // prevent default submitting and display the next form
        });
        // and so on
    });
    </script>
</head>
```